# video stream in ros

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i started to stream video using ros by using ssh to connect to the target system where i have attached the camera. I launched a gscam node there and it is working. then in the other system i exported ros_master_uri. When i rostopic list the nodes. I shows /gscam/image_raw publishing. But when i run rosrun image_view image_view image:=/gscam/image_raw the window opens but no video. I did try compressed transport also. Could you please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9394/video-stream-in-ros/) by [rinosh1989](https://answers.ros.org/users/145/rinosh1989/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you export your ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME on the other machine also?
Otherwise could you post:

```
$env | grep ROS
```

And a image of rxgraph with all topics listed could solve the problem.
Is there something published on the topic?

```
rostopic hz /gscam/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1